# Can measure induce a topology on a Set?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

When I was taught metric spaces in Topology, I came across the idea that metric defined on a set can induce a topology by creating a basis (open balls). If we have a measure defined on a set, can it induce a topology on a set?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant "measure," you might be interested in [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80026/the-metric-space-associated-to-a-measure-space).

Note that $A\Delta B$ is the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:
https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2036267.pdf

Different from the previous answer about defining a metric on the sigma-algebra on X, this one should be about defining a topology on X.